# Android Studio - Invalid Resource Directory ('xhdpi' Specifically)

Tags: android, directory, resources

I recently updated the 'ic_launcher' files in my app. When I ran the program, I got an error: Error:

***'Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. C:\Users\x\AndroidStudioProjects\x\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhpdi: Error: Invalid resource directory name'***

So the error is in my xhdpi file, I checked to see what was wrong and discovered nothing; everything looked fine. I'm not sure why its my xhpdi file however.

Comment: why do you need `xhpdi` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says:

> mipmap-xhpdi: Error: Invalid resource directory name

That directory should be named mipmap-xhdpi.  You can open the directory in a file browser and rename it.  That should fix it.

Comment: My problem is that somehow there was a single space at each one of my mipmap folder names.